# Not seeing TWMDropFiles after file drop into ListView

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, vcl

I'm trying to follow the instructions here, but only accept dragged files in a specific `ListView` as opposed to the whole form:
http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=11

I have this in the `FormCreate` procedure:

```
  DragAcceptFiles(CustomAppsListView.Handle, True);
```

This in the private declarations:

```
procedure WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
```

And basically the exact same code for the `WMDropFiles` example, with some DebugStrings:

```
procedure TMainFrm.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles);
var
  DropH: HDROP;               // drop handle
  DroppedFileCount: Integer;  // number of files dropped
  FileNameLength: Integer;    // length of a dropped file name
  FileName: string;           // a dropped file name
  I: Integer;                 // loops thru all dropped files
  DropPoint: TPoint;          // point where files dropped
begin
  inherited;
  // Store drop handle from the message
  DropH := Msg.Drop;
  try
        OutputDebugString(PChar('Entered Try'));
    // Get count of files dropped
    DroppedFileCount := DragQueryFile(DropH, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);
    // Get name of each file dropped and process it
    for I := 0 to Pred(DroppedFileCount) do
    begin
      // get length of file name
      FileNameLength := DragQueryFile(DropH, I, nil, 0);
      // create string large enough to store file
      // (Delphi allows for #0 terminating character automatically)
      SetLength(FileName, FileNameLength);
      // get the file name
        OutputDebugString(PChar(FileName));
      DragQueryFile(DropH, I, PChar(FileName), FileNameLength + 1);
      // process file name (application specific)
      // ... processing code here
    end;
    // Optional: Get point at which files were dropped
    DragQueryPoint(DropH, DropPoint);
    // ... do something with drop point here
  finally
    // Tidy up - release the drop handle
    // don't use DropH again after this
    DragFinish(DropH);
  end;
  // Note we handled message
  Msg.Result := 0;
end;
```

When I drag a file over, I see the cursor switch to the "drag accept" cursor, but when I drop I'm not seeing any file names come out. In fact, I don't think I'm entering this message handling block of code at all. Is there something else I need to do or add, maybe to the `ListView` itself to get this to fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are registering the ListView's window to receive the messages, but then you are trying to handle them in the MainForm.  That is why you never see them - they are not sent to the MainForm's window.  You need to subclass the ListView's `WindowProc` property to receive the messages that are sent to the ListView's window.

You also need to take into account that VCL windows are not persistent.  The ListView's `HWND` is most likely going to be recreated dynamically at least once during its lifetime, thus losing your `DragAcceptFiles()` registration.  That is another reason to subclass the ListView's `WindowProc` property, so you can re-register every time the ListView's window gets recreated.

A better option is to derive a new component (or at least an interceptor class) from `TListView` and have it override the virtual `CreateWnd()` and `DestroyWnd()` methods to handle the registration:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  ...;

type
  TListViewDroppedFilesEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Files: TStrings; const DropPt: TPoint) of object;

  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  private
    FOnDroppedFiles: TListViewDroppedFilesEvent;
    procedure SetOnDroppedFiles(Value: TListViewDroppedFilesEvent);
    procedure WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  public
    property OnDroppedFiles: TListViewDroppedFilesEvent read FOnDroppedFiles write SetOnDroppedFiles;
  end;

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    CustomAppsListView: TListView;
    ...
  private
    procedure CustomAppsListViewDroppedFiles(Sender: TObject; Files: TStrings; const DropPt: TPoint);
    ...
  end;

...

implementation

procedure TListView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnDroppedFiles) then DragAcceptFiles(Handle, True);
end;

procedure TListView.DestroyWnd;
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, False);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TListView.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles);
var
  DropH: HDROP;               // drop handle
  DroppedFileCount: Integer;  // number of files dropped
  FileNameLength: Integer;    // length of a dropped file name
  FileName: string;           // a dropped file name
  I: Integer;                 // loops thru all dropped files
  DropPoint: TPoint;          // point where files dropped
  Files: TStringList;
begin
  inherited;
  if not Assigned(FOnDroppedFiles) then Exit;
  // Store drop handle from the message
  DropH := Msg.Drop;
  try
    // Get count of files dropped
    DroppedFileCount := DragQueryFile(DropH, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);
    Files := TStringList.Create;
    try
      // Get name of each file dropped and process it
      for I := 0 to Pred(DroppedFileCount) do
      begin
        // get length of file name
        FileNameLength := DragQueryFile(DropH, I, nil, 0);
        // create string large enough to store file
        // (Delphi allows for #0 terminating character automatically)
        SetLength(FileName, FileNameLength);
        // get the file name
        OutputDebugString(PChar(FileName));
        DragQueryFile(DropH, I, PChar(FileName), FileNameLength + 1);
        Files.Add(FileName);
      end;
      // Optional: Get point at which files were dropped
      DragQueryPoint(DropH, DropPoint);
      FOnDroppedFiles(Self, Files, DropPoint);
    finally
      Files.Free;
    end;
  finally
    // Tidy up - release the drop handle
    // don't use DropH again after this
    DragFinish(DropH);
  end;
  // Note we handled message
  Msg.Result := 0;
end;

procedure TListView.SetOnDroppedFiles(Value: TListViewDroppedFilesEvent);
begin
  if (TMethod(FOnDroppedFiles).Code <> TMethod(Value).Code) or
     (TMethod(FOnDroppedFiles).Data <> TMethod(Value).Data) then
  begin
    FOnDroppedFiles := Value;
    if HandleAllocated then
      DragAcceptFiles(Handle, Assigned(FOnDroppedFiles));
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CustomAppsListView.OnDroppedFiles := CustomAppsListViewDroppedFiles;
end;

procedure TMainForm.CustomAppsListViewDroppedFiles(Sender: TObject; Files: TStrings; const DropPt: TPoint);
begin
  // process Files (application specific)
  // ... processing code here
  // ... do something with DropPt here
end;

...

end.
```

Comment: okay, I think I follow most of that logic, but I can't compile your example code, the `if FOnDroppedFiles <> Value then` line gives this error: `[dcc32 Error] mainForm.pas(3510): E2035 Not enough actual parameters`

Comment: also not sure if you want to edit this in, but for me I had to change the class line to: `TListView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView)`